# How to connect different types of controllers?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Maybe this is not the simplest question that i'd asked on stack overflow however i hope someone could help me.

I have 3 *UIViewControllers*, some of them (2 of those) are *UITableViewController* which subviews are handled by a *UINavigationController*; the last is a custom view controller.

My goal is to have those **3 controllers handled** by a *UITabBarController*, easy task! The problem is that **i want to access those from a HomeViewController too** and also have the opportunity to hide and show the NavigationBar and the TabBar when i would.

Here is the complete flow of the application

1) Home View Controller with different buttons (no nav, no tab bar, no status bar)

2) When user tap on a button -> segue -> one of those five (nav, tab bar and status bar would have to appear).

I thought that maybe i have to embed those five in a *UITabBarController* but then how can i connect the buttons from the Home View Controller to the right view Controller??

This is kinda like what i want to obtain.

[image: storyboard diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do to present a view controller after clicking a button is the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
UIViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need to make sure you put the "myViewController" in the storyboard ID.

Comment: If you are not doing any preparatory work you don't need a segue but you can trigger a segue programmatically as well. `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"indentifier" sender:nil];`

Comment: I tried your solution but the tab bar appears empty!

Comment: Actually i'm having bad issues with priority from the Navigation Controller and TabBarController, i think one solution is to made a fake tabbar

Comment: Sorry but I lost you. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe put a diagram in the question